# Where should I use &v: &V to describe a parameter in function signatures?

Tags: rust

You can find the below code on [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=67879a1d35d53c55000e18353d214743).

```
fn main() {
    #[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
    struct Foo {
        bar: u32,
    }

    fn take_ref(&f: &Foo) {
        println!("{:?}", f);
    }

    fn take_foo(f: Foo) {
        println!("{:?}", f);
    }

    let f = Foo {
        bar: 1,
    };

    take_ref(&f);
    println!("{:?}", f);

    take_foo(f.clone());
    println!("{:?}", f);
}
```

Are these functions, `take_ref` and `take_foo`, the same?
When should I use &v: &V rather than v: V?

Comment: It would probably be more interesting with a non Copy struct. Or with mutable access.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52203375/referencing-dereferencing-a-vector-element-in-a-for-loop/52203694#52203694

Comment: @DenysSéguret, thanks for replying. Doesn't `V` have to implement Copy? It won't compile if I take Copy out. Could you provide a short example? Thanks

Comment: _"It won't compile..."_ — I think that was Denys' point. It shows the difference.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I think you should never use the `&f: &Foo` form. The only reason it is accepted by the compiler is because function parameters (like `let` assignment) are actually irrefutable patterns. This can be seen in the error message if you try to put a general pattern:

```
fn take_option (Some (f): Option<Foo>) {
    println!("{:?}", f);
}
```

does not complain about invalid syntax, but instead gives this error message:

```
error[E0005]: refutable pattern in function argument: `None` not covered
  --> src/main.rs:15:21
   |
15 |     fn take_option (Some (f): Option<Foo>) {
   |                     ^^^^^^^^ pattern `None` not covered
```

Using patterns as function arguments allows nice things like automatic tuple, array, or structure destructuring:

```
fn take_tuple ((x, y): (i32, i32)) {
    println!("x: {}, y: {}", x, y);
}

fn take_array ([x, y]: [i32; 2]) {
    println!("x: {}, y: {}", x, y);
}

fn take_foo (Foo { bar: bar }: Foo) {
    println!("bar: {}", bar);
}

population
   .iter()
   .enumerate()
   .map (|(rank, person)| { ... });
```